# How to rename tables in Microsoft access dynamically

Tags: ms-access

I have an ms access database with 6 tables. Table names are long and have spaces/slashes. I need to rename the tables every day so that it's shorter and has no spaces or slashes as below:

table 123/abc 2022 --> table123

any ideas if this can be done dynamically(automated) will be appreciated.

Is it doable with VBA?

Comment: Yes, it can be done by VBA? But why your table in such format?

Comment: You can try `DoCmd.Rename "Old Employees Table", acTable, "Employees"` just use a loop to rename all tables. See this article from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.rename

Comment: How are these tables coming in that way - is it via an import process? If so, just run the rename in VBA code - split table name by "/" and rename using virst element in variant array. Much easier if you post you vba code

Comment: Cross post https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/rename-access-tables-dynamically.323773/